# What to do with this dangerous code?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, code

A user posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39178263/looking-to-reuse-some-old-vbasic-code-i-dont-quite-understand).

I have answered without giving the answer purposely, and flagged the question to the attention of the moderators.

Although it doesn't seem to me that the aim of this user is to execute any malicious activity, this code can be terribly dangerous and should not spread on Stack Overflow IMO.

What's the best way to handle that kind of question?

It's because I am feeling guilty to have answered that I ask this on meta. Should I delete my answer?

Edit: I deleted my answer.

Comment: Answering might have been the worst action if you wan't to see this going away.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ See my edit at the end of my question. It answers your comment.

Comment: Hmya, a sad aspect of Q+A here is that it is rare to ever learn anything from bad answers.  Your answer was wrong, it is not dangerous, you can only use the flag when the code runs with a very privileged admin account.  At which point you can already execute any code you want.  Meanwhile, the meta effect did quite a number on that question.  That's rather sad, isn't it?  Please vote to re-open the question.

Comment: In what way is this code "dangerous"? The Windows operating system does have a security model. If your IT department isn't smart enough to actually understand that security model, and you can trivially bypass it by calling standard API functions, then that's the *real* danger. Anyway, as has been discussed countless times on Meta, it's really not our job to police what people will do with code they post. There's nothing fundamentally wrong with this question. If you'd prefer not to answer it because it makes you uncomfortable, then don't, but beating up on the person who asked it is not OK.

Comment: It is a dangerous code : [You can circumvent AppLocker rules by using an Office macro on a computer that is running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2](https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/kb/2532445)

Comment: I won't start arguing here, just read it and make your own opinion

Comment: Note that, since the question has now been re-opened, I would upvote an answer that pointed out the vulnerabilities in that code, linked to the knowledge base article that discusses the patch, and otherwise provided a canonical reference pointing out the problems. That way, we get the best of both words. Information that wants to be free is free, and yet if a system administrator finds this code and tries to look for a solution, they end up with the answer they need.

Answer (score 0):

> **Should I delete my answer???**

Yes, you should. Answering will just help to keep what you consider dangerous.

I have just down voted the question, and close voted (you can use a flag also) being unclear, since there's not even a question at all (well, you can guess the OP want's to have an explanation *"Why this works?"*).

Comment: done. And to be honest I am feeling better now :)